# Knockout arrayFirst with MVC List

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

My MVC view model contains a number of properties including a list of objects.

This model is bound to a knockout model as follows:

```
 viewModel = new DynamicModelLoading(@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson()));
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

When looking at the knockout model I can see that my list has been successfully created as an array.

The problem I'm having is that whenever I use arrayFirst on the array it always returns null. I can create an observablearray in javascript and arrayFirst works fine.

```
var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(viewModel.activeList(), function (item) {
    return 2 === item.id;
});
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong to be able to apply arrayFirst on an array that has been bound from my MVC model?

Comment: Can you show what `viewModel.activeList()` looks like, perhaps with a console dump of it?

Comment: try `return 2 == item.id()` i hope it is observable . cheers

Comment: Ok, that's giving a bit more insight, but I'm still no closer to understanding why. JSON.stringify(viewModel.activeList()) simply returns  "[{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]". But in the Knockout Context I can see an array full of valid objects.

Comment: try @supercool suggestion else if it is not observable then try return 2 == item.id;

Comment: Yep, tried that. Doesn't work. Seems to be something to do with the knockout mapping but I can't work out what

Comment: give us a sample fiddle with complete code so we can fix it for you .

Comment: Ok, I've finally sussed it. The mapper is creating the observable array as an array of objects full of observable properties. Therefore simply needed to state return 2 === item.id(); rather than return 2 === item.id;

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've finally sussed it. The mapper is creating the observable array as an array of objects full of observable properties. Therefore simply needed to state:

`return 2 === item.id();`

rather than return

```
2 === item.id;
```